# Number of Rectangles

Tags: combinatorics

Considering that a square is also a rectangle, how many rectangles are there in the figure below?

I think it is $\frac{5(5-1)}{2} \cdot \frac{6(6-1)}{2}$, but I don't know how correct my belief is.

Can someone give a more detailed answer to this question.

[image: Figure One]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. A rectangle is determined by **choosing** two vertical lines from the $5$ available, and two horizontal lines from the $6$ available. This can be done in $\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{2}$ ways.